# How do I write code for a 2d Gaussian Kernel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, gaussian

I'm trying to make a nxn Gaussian kernel.

The formula I'm following is as given

[image]

Here is what I've got so far:

```
# sigma(standard deviation) and muu(mean) are the parameters of gaussian
def gkern(kernel_size, sigma=1, muu=0):
 
    # Initializing value of x,y as grid of kernel size
    # in the range of kernel size
 
    x, y = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(
            -(kernel_size - 1) / 2., 
            (kernel_size - 1) / 2., 
            kernel_size
        ),
        np.linspace(
            -(kernel_size - 1) / 2., 
            (kernel_size - 1) / 2., 
            kernel_size
        ),
    )

                       
    dst = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
 
    # lower normal part of gaussian
    normal = 1/(2.0 * np.pi * sigma**2)
 
    # Calculating Gaussian filter
    gauss = np.exp(-((dst-muu)**2 / (2.0 * sigma**2))) * normal
    return gauss
```

This code works fine for 5x5 Gaussian kernels, where I get [image] , and the "expected" output is
[image]

However, when I change the kernel size to 3, the output I get is
[image]
where the "expected" output is
[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code.

If you're going to ask "What is wrong with using the other code?"

```
import numpy as np
   
def gkern(l=5, sig=1.):
    """\
    creates gaussian kernel with side length `l` and a sigma of `sig`
    """
    ax = np.linspace(-(l - 1) / 2., (l - 1) / 2., l)
    gauss = np.exp(-0.5 * np.square(ax) / np.square(sig))
    kernel = np.outer(gauss, gauss)
    return kernel / np.sum(kernel)

gkern(l= 3)
```

This is the code. I don't really understand it & I'm trying to be faithful to the formula.

Comment: How could this possibly be the expected output for a 3x3 Gaussian kernel? For the 3x3 case, you are evaluating the function at the values -1, 0, 1. For the 5x5 case, you are evaluating at -2, -1, 0, 1, 2. Why would you expect the evaluation of the function at -1, 0 and 1 to return different values in the 3x3 case than in the 5x5 case?

Comment: Your example code gives a hint. At the end `kernel` is devided by `np.sum(kernel)`. Typically a kernel is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Normalization) which is not the case in your solution.

Comment: @Flow , does that mean that my own code (the first one) is correct? For the "example code", I tried adding all the numbers together, and the output is 1.0. This is not the case for my own code. I also don't really understand the linspace, and what the ideal values for linspace is.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer your initial question as well as the additional ones in your comment:

Oftentimes you want to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Normalization) a filter kernel in order keep an average brightness. This step is missing in your function.
You have to change only the last line to:

```
return gauss / np.sum(gauss)
```

That way your matrices also add up to 1.
What you implemented is a more generalized form of the 2d gaussian, which can be off-centered by choosing muu != 0. Right now I can't think of a situation where you want to do that.
About linspace:
a) You used it already in your function, but state you don't really understand it. Be careful with such a way of programming. These functions are typically well documented and you should understand them before you are using them.

`np.linspace` generates an evenly spaced sequence of values, from a start to an end value with a certain step size. The most natural one would be 0, 1, 2 ...

And as I stated earlier, you want your kernel to be symmetrical. A gaussian is symmetrical around 0, therefore the values you feed into a gaussian should be also symmetrical around 0. Therefore 0, 1, 2... needs to be shifted to negative values. ...., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2...

Of course you can ask, why choosing e.g. +/- 1, +/-2, ... and not +/- 0.1, +/-0.2, ... to feed into the gaussian. Actually you can use both, but instead adjusting sigma should give the ability to do the same.